# convert array of integer coordinates to typed array

Tags: javascript

I use big arrays of x,y integer coordinates stored like this `[x0, y0, x1, y1, x2, y2, ..., xN, yN]`

For using less memory and maybe improving performance, I would like to store those arrays in typed arrays. I found out that the `Int32Array` can store the range of coordinates.

How can I convert those arrays to `Int32Array`, can I just do the following:

```
var coords = [-8774772, ​​6713301, -8774922, 6712895, -8774289, 6711450, ..., -8774772, ​​6713301]
var typedArray = new Int32Array(coords);
```

Or should I use `ArrayBuffer`?

Also, are there optimizations that could be done to use less memory, for instance converting coordinates to fit in `Int16Array`?

Comment: What is your current performance issue you are trying to improve? What are we benchmarking against? Just need to know so we know if what we suggest is improving the performance.

Comment: Looping on coordinates to draw geometry to canvas, but more than that is the high memory consumption when using normal array

Comment: OK, I see. Do you have a small working example that we can use to measure alternatives on?

Comment: Do you need the rendering to canvas part or just a relatively big array with a looping benchmark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use the typed arrays or dataview for that, I'll go with dataview:

```
var coords = [-8774772, 6713301, -8774922, 6712895, -8774289, 6711450, -8774772, 6713301];
var buff = new ArrayBuffer(coords.length*4);
var dv = new DataView(buff);
coords.forEach(function(d,i){
    dv.setInt32(i*4,d);
});
dv.getInt32(0); //-8774772
dv.getInt32(4); //6713301
dv.getInt32(8); //-8774922
dv.getInt32(12); //6712895
```

As for performance, I have not seen any compelling evidence that they are much faster than using plain arrays. I do not even know if the vendors use normal arrays behind the scenes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can I ask why the DataView over the typed array?

Comment: You have control over the byte offsets. So you can in fact read it out of frame if you want. But it doesn't mean its better or faster. Ah I also forget to mention the endianness as well, you can provide a third option as true for little endian